# git rebase from master to remote branch.!

Tags: git

I already googled, and read many document.
but Unfortunately I cannot understand them all

My situation is.

```
git branch -r
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
origin/team/myteam

git branch -a
master
team/myteam
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/team/myteam
```

and Now I like to merge every patches from master to remote `mybranch`.

I tried

> git checkout team/myteam
>
> git rebase master

```
git status
On branch team/myteam 
Your branch and 'origin/team/myteam' have diverged,
and have 238 and 18 diffrent commits each, respectively.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

it seems works.. but `push` returns error..

I use gerrit.

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/team/mybranch  
...
..
remote: Resolving
deltas: 100% (14481/14481) remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
To ssh://156.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx  ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/team/myteam (change 228 closed) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://156.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx
```

Comment: _but push returns error.._ - what error?

Comment: what error is returned?

Comment: Thanks guys, I edited & leaved my error message.

Comment: Rebase rewrites history, and in this case the remote is refusing to accept it because of that. It's generally a bad idea to use rebase on branches that are available for others - is there some reason why you didn't use `git merge` instead?

Comment: either use `push -f` or use `merge` instead of `rebase` (I recommend merging, especially if you are new to git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to push to `origin/team/myteam` and you are up to date in `team/myteam`.

If you rebase `team/myteam` with `master`, you are rewriting the history of your branch `team/myteam` so Git doesn't allow you to push it as it conflicts with the history it has in `origin/team/myteam`.

If you are sure of what you want to do (rewrite the history on the origin repo), you can force push with :

```
 git push --force
```

Beware that your team mates might have troubles when they will pull `origin/team/myteam` : rewriting the shared history is not something recommended.

You might want to do a `merge` instead of a `rebase` : in that case you can do a simple push and you will skip potential troubles.

Comment: right, if then, what is recommened way to push master's commit to origin/team/myteam?

Comment: You shoulw never do Push and gerrit doesn't allow that bu default

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a workflow one.

Since you have not historically rebased master under the team/myteam branch before pushing to the remote, this is not possible without a `force push`. It has not been rebased before and this is why the branches have diverged. In it's current state pushing the rebased merge to the remote is impossible without a force push. Very generally speaking `force push` is not a good choice unless no one else using the remote branch.

There are many ways to resolve the problem of your local and the remote branches having diverged.

- You could do a `git merge` locally then `git push` to get your remote branch up to date. This probably the simplest.
- You could deprecate the existing remote branch and push to a new remote branch for your team then coordinate with the team members to start using the new remote branch.
- You could `force push` to the remote myteam branch and coordinate with the team members to merge the force push with their local repositories. This could be painful.

To do a git merge on myteam (i.e., branchname), you may need to delete your local branch in order do a clean merge. It's `git branch -D branchname` to delete a local branch. Then...

```
git checkout branchname
git pull -r origin branchname
git merge master
git push origin branchname
```

**In the future, you should rebase your local branch with master before each and every push to the remote.** There are quicker ways to achieve the rebase than the commands written below, but I've made this verbose for demonstration purposes.

```
git checkout mybranch
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/team/mybranch
```

PS. Sorry, I don't know Gerrit.

PPS. In git, `force push` is a combination of  two operations, `delete` remote branch and `push` local branch to remote.

Answer (score -1):

1) Since you use gerrit and you get change is closed that means you can't push for same ChangeID

2) You workflow is incorrect
You should do git fetch origin and then git rebase origin master & Commit and push